# The board of directors in companies

Tags: board-of-directors, corporate-governance

I understand how a board of directors works. They are elected by the investors. I have a few questions about it.

- Do directors belong to certain agencies or do they work for the government or do they work for the investors?
- What background, legal status, or other requirements are there for directors?
- What are their obligations?
- Can an investor be a member of the board rather than electing someone else to represent him/her?

Answer (score 4):

Boards of Directors are required for corporations by nearly all jurisdictions.  Some jurisdictions have almost self-defeating requirements however, such as in tax havens.

Boards of Directors are compensated by the company for which they sit.  Historically, they have set their own compensation almost always with tight qualitative legal bounds, but in the US, that has now changed, so investors now set Director compensation.  Directors are typically not given wages or salary for work but compensation for expenses.  For larger companies, this is semantics since compensation averages around one quarter of a million of USD.

Regulations almost always proscribe agencies such as other corporations from sitting on boards and individuals convicted of serious crimes as well.  Some jurisdictions will even restrict directories to other qualities such as solvency.

While directors are elected by shareholders, their obligations are normally to the company, and each jurisdiction has its own set of rules for this.  Almost always, directors are forbidden from selling access to their votes.

Directors are almost always elected by holders of voting stock after a well-publicized announcement and extended time period.

Investors are almost never restricted from sitting on a board so long as they meet the requirements described above.

Comment: So let's assume the investor elected someone, therefore s/he pays that member an annual salary ?

Comment: @user3103230 No, the compensation is paid by the company.

Comment: Typo corrected: No. The company pays the salary, since board member is a company position as specified in the company's papers. Note too that "the investor" can only elect someone if they own the majority of voting stock; if not they need to get enough other folks with votes to agree with them. If you own voting shares you'll get yearly requests to vote for directors, among other things, usually as part of the annual stockholder's meeting. (This is true for US corporations, anyway; can't vouch for elsewhere but the concept of a corporation seems pretty well standardized.)